# gscam error - "Failed to PAUSE stream, check your gstreamer configuration." and "Failed to initialize gscam stream!"

Tags: ros, gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tryed to launch a file on my computer that was working fine in another computer  on my lab, something like [Section 3](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam#Running).

I found some solutions like :

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0

ll /dev/video*
```

The device should now have all the permissions:

```
crwxrwxrwx+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jul 21 18:36 /dev/video0
```

and I could launch it correctly with:

```
roslaunch gscam v4l.launch
```

but it fails, giving me the error:

```
[FATAL] [1437501492.196615126]: Failed to PAUSE stream, check your gstreamer configuration.
[FATAL] [1437501492.197344548]: Failed to initialize gscam stream!
```

.

I tryed everything and it just doesn't work.

P.S.: I have Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, ROS Groovy and libgstreamer0.10 if it matters.

.
.

My launch file contains exactly this:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Set this to your camera's name -->
  <arg name="cam_name" value="creative_cam" />

  <!-- Start the GSCAM node -->
  <env name="GSCAM_CONFIG" value="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1,width=640,height=480 ! ffmpegcolorspace " />
  <node pkg="gscam" type="gscam" name="$(arg cam_name)">
    <param name="camera_name" value="$(arg cam_name)" />
    <remap from="camera/image_raw" to="$(arg cam_name)/image_raw" />
  </node>

  <!-- View the raw and rectified output -->
  <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="creative_view" >
    <remap from="image" to="/$(arg cam_name)/image_raw" />
  </node>
    
</launch>
```

Thank you for your attention ,

Nelson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214247/gscam-error---%22failed-to-pause-stream,-check-your-gstreamer-configuration.%22-and-%22failed-to-initialize-gscam-stream!%22/) by [nelsoncampos](https://answers.ros.org/users/23285/nelsoncampos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not `export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"` and `roslaunch gscam v4l.launch` in the same terminal.

http://answers.ros.org/question/211757/error-in-gscam/

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nelsoncampos](https://answers.ros.org/users/23285/nelsoncampos/) on 2015-07-22**:
Thank you PJLai but I only use one of those. i just put it in the launch file like the section 3 says. Should I also do the export in another terminal or it is not necessário to work?

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-22**:
Can you show me your v4l.launch? You can edit your question and paste it.

**Comment by [nelsoncampos](https://answers.ros.org/users/23285/nelsoncampos/) on 2015-07-22**:
Hello again Po-Jen-Lai. I just edited the question.

This launch file works fine in other computer from my lab but not at mine.

"I have Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, ROS Groovy and libgstreamer0.10 if it matters." **just formatted yesterday**.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-24**:
Your launch file works perfectly on my laptop, I cannot reproduce your problem...Do you have other error messages except for the two lines in your question? There's no enough info to debug.